# Can I implement the lattice deformation to an animation?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I need help. I have a weapon I've created comprised of 5 parts. One of the parts has a lattice with 2 shapekeys. I haven't yet hit apply on the lattice modifier, but it still affects my object. I have used the two shapekeys to simulate a movement, and it looks pretty good. The thing is I move them in the shapekey editor and not in the action editor. The Action Editor wont save any keyframes when I mess with the shapekeys for some reason. Well I sent my blend to Unity and the object with the lattice does not get animated. Any ideas?

Comment: Some screenshots would help.

Comment: Hi, please only ask one question at a time. Post separate questions for separate issues.

Comment: I wouldn't think Unity would support Lattice deform, as modifiers are applied when the mesh is exported.

Comment: Unless the questions are directly related please use different posts for each one! How is someone looking for an issue similar to yours going to guess that the information he is looking for is buried on a totally different question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity doesn't support lattice deformation, but it does support bone deformation which can be used in many cases.

For example (left side is lattice, right side is bone):
[image]

You can get it to look even better if your especially careful with the weight painting.

Comment: Damn. The lattice animation I have going in Blender looks really good. It'll be kind of complicated to do with bones. Oh well, I'll just mess with the vertices themselves, it'll probably be easier than messing with the bones.